# How do I find the sum of items in a text file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building a pizza application. The users are able either to pick a standard pizza or to customize a pizza. Each pizza has its own price stored in a list as doubles. These prices are also stored in a text file.

I have managed to display the prices of the pizzas in a `ListBox` (code below) but I do not know how to find the sum of the prices for them.

There is always a variation in price so I need to transform the prices into variables and add them together, but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
foreach (var item in listPrice.Items)
{
    File.AppendAllText("price.txt", item + Environment.NewLine);
}

using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("price.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        finalPrice.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Piece of advice: Don't use `double` for monetary values; use `Decimal`.

Comment: i will change them now, thank you :D

Comment: Why aren't you storing the prices in the ListBox as numeric values ?

Comment: i have 4 forms each of them closing when the next one opens. if I will create a list i think the value inside it will be deleted, right? But i am not sure about that. i will do more research on that, then come back

Comment: @BogdanDragos: I know you're new here, but this question (and also your other questions) are extremely low quality. Please make an attempt to include more information about your problem, format your code better, spend more time formatting your question text into logical sections. I've edited your question above, please review it to make sure my additions are correct, and please take this extra effort on your next question or you will continue to get downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using text files and strings is not a good approach, but here is an example on how you might read `price.txt` and sum the values.

```
List<string> price = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader("price.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        price.Add(line);
        finalPrice.Items.Add(line);
    }
}

//Convert string to double, then sum all lines
var sum = price.Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).Sum();
```

The special part is the last line, once all of the prices are the list `price`, you can convert all the strings to numbers with [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) and then call the Linq method [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx)